# Following integral?

Tags: definite-integrals

How to solve the following:

$$\int_1^{x} \lfloor t\rfloor dt $$

I can conclude the answer is asymptotic to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2} x^2 - \frac{1}{2} x$ and specifically it looks just like $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}x^2$ except entirely linear (basically between consecutive integer points the function is a line that passes through both points)

How to express this though?

Comment: I mean asymptotic to 1/2 x^2 - 1/2 x

Comment: Plot the region first. Use geometry to solve this. You shouldn't get singularities

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: Welcome to MSE! It helps readability to format questions using Mathjax (see FAQ). I did this one as example. Please make sure I got it correct. Regards.

Comment: Here is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/how-to-solve-an-definite-integral-of-floor-valute-function).

Comment: By the way Maple 17 and wolfram alpha give no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break the integral up at every integer bigger than $1$. That is,
$$
\int_1^x \lfloor t \rfloor \, dt = \sum_{n = 1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1} \int_{n}^{n+1}\lfloor t \rfloor \, dt + \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x \lfloor t \rfloor \, dt.
$$
On each interval $[n,n+1)$, $\lfloor t \rfloor = n$ and $\lfloor t \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor$ on $[\lfloor x \rfloor, x)$ so that
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_1^x \lfloor t \rfloor \, dt &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1} \int_{n}^{n+1} n \, dt + \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^x \lfloor x \rfloor \, dt\\ 
&= \left(\sum_{n = 1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1} n\right) + (x - \lfloor x \rfloor) \lfloor x \rfloor\\
&= \frac{1}{2}(\lfloor x \rfloor - 1)\lfloor x \rfloor + (x - \lfloor x \rfloor) \lfloor x \rfloor\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the input.

Comment: You did this by assuming that floor(x) was a constant function I presume?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas, Indeed $t \mapsto \lfloor t \rfloor$ is constant on each interval $[n, n+1)$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$. (This function is non-constant globally of course, though it is irrelevant to Suugaku's solution.)

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the integral into two part by splitting the domain of integration into two parts:

$$ \int_{1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \lfloor t \rfloor \, dt + \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^{x} \lfloor t \rfloor \, dt $$

But here we present a method using the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration:

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{x} \lfloor t \rfloor \, dt
&=\left[ t \lfloor t \rfloor \right]_{1^{-}}^{x} - \int_{1^{-}}^{x} t \, d\lfloor t \rfloor \\
&= x\lfloor x \rfloor - \sum_{1\leq n \leq x} n \\
&= x\lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor(\lfloor x \rfloor + 1)}{2} \\
&= \frac{x(x-1)}{2} - \frac{\{ x \}(\{ x \}-1)}{2},
\end{align*}

where $\{ x \} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: Where can I learn about Lebsque-Stieljes Integration?