# Calculate the integral $\int_0^{x} (\lfloor t+1 \rfloor)^3dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Here's the integral, 
$$\int_0^{x} (\lfloor t+1 \rfloor)^3dt$$

I have some knowledge of computing the integrals of discontinous functions but the cube function and the independent variable limit confused me a bit.
Also note the cube is outside the floor function as written.
Thanks for any help..

Comment: Split the interval of integration into multiple parts at strategically chosen points.

Comment: Tried but i am not getting anywhere with that

Comment: Can you post the solution please?

Comment: Where did you split?

Comment: cube roots of the quantity inside floor

Comment: If $x$ confuses you, use $a$.

Comment: Bad choice of points. Go by the _value_ of the integrand.

Comment: The integrand is complicated in the whole line but simple in the intervals with integer endpoints.

Comment: @Daneil for example? can you give me first two splits please?

Comment: Think about $[n,n+1]$

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/how-to-solve-an-definite-integral-of-floor-valute-function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_0^x [ t+1 ]^3 dt = \sum_{i=1}^{[x]}\int_{i-1}^{i}[ t+1 ]^3 dt + \int_{[x]}^{x}[ t+1 ]^3 dt $$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{[x]}\int_{i-1}^{i}i^3 dt + \int_{[x]}^{x}[x+1]^3 dt =\sum_{i=1}^{[x]}i^3+ [x+1]^3\cdot(x-[x]) $$
$$ = \frac{[x]^4+2[x]^3+[x]^2}{4} + [x+1]^3\cdot(x-[x])$$

Comment: What if $x$ isn't an integer?

Comment: The last term of sum should be different in case of non-integer $x$, like $(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)\cdot (\lfloor x \rfloor)^3$

Comment: I corrected it.

Comment: You have a small mistake, it's $$\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^x (\lfloor x \rfloor + 1)^3\, dt$$ (and consequently the last summand is $(\lfloor x\rfloor + 1)^3\cdot (x - \lfloor x\rfloor)$. But in principle it's fine now.

Comment: The integrand is ${\lfloor 1+t \rfloor}^3 $ not $[1+t]^3$.

Comment: Got it all Thanks @DanielFischer and user38034 :)

Comment: So does this method work for all discontinous integrals ?

Comment: @Simar You can always split at the discontinuities. But of course not always there is such a nice sum for the sum of the integrals over the intervals of continuity.