# expected value of a $e^{-2|x|}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f(x)=e^{-2|x|}$

Find:

1. $E(X)$
2. $E(|X|)$
3. $E(x')$ where $x'$ denotes the largest integer not greater than $x$.

I'm stuck on this question and am confused about how to use the modulus sign. I feel I need to show it separately for cases when $x\ge0$ and $x\le0$ but I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is $X$? How does it relate to $f$? I'm guessing maybe $f$ is the pdf of $X$ or something?

Comment: Also, if that interpretation is right, how does $X$ relate to $|X|$?  Also also, what on Earth is $x$, if not a typo?

Comment: The Maple code $$restart; with(Statistics): $$ $$ X := RandomVariable(Distribution(PDF = (t ->exp(-2*abs(t)))));$$ $$Y := floor(X):
Mean(Y);
 $$ gives the answer to your third question $$\frac {-2+{{\rm e}^{-2}}+{{\rm e}^{2}}}{ \left( {{\rm e}^{2}}-1
 \right)  \left( {{\rm e}^{-2}}-1 \right) }
 .$$

Answer (score 2):

By definition, 
$$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-2|x|}\,dx.\tag{1}$$

To evaluate this integral is easy. First, a technical thin, the integral does converge. The function $xe^{-2|x|}$ is an odd function, so the integral is $0$.

We have
$$E(|X|)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|e^{-2|x|}\,dx.\tag{2}$$
Now the integrand is symmetric about the $y$-axis, so we find the integral from $0$ to $\infty$, and double.

To find the integral from $0$ to $\infty$, we need
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-2x}\,dx.$$
We can use integration by parts, or recall that the exponential with parameter $2$ has mean $\frac{1}{2}$. That tells us that $\int_0^\infty (x)2e^{-2x}=\frac{1}{2}$.

The greatest integer one takes a bit more woek to analyze. The integral breaks up into parts. From $0$ to $1$ we are integrating $0\cdot e^{-2x}$. From $1$ to $2$ we are integrating $1\cdot e^{-2x}$, and so on.

So we get 
$$(1)\frac{1}{2}(e^{-2}-e^{-4})+(2)\frac{1}{2}(e^{-4}-e^{-6})+(3)\frac{1}{2}(e^{-6}-e^{-8})+\cdots.$$
This is a geometric series, not hard to evaluate.

However, we can be tricky, and do the negative part, hoping for cancellation. We get
$$(-1)\frac{1}{2}(e^{0}-e^{2})+(-2)\frac{1}{2}(e^{-2}-e^{-4})+(-3)\frac{1}{2}(e^{-4}-e^{-6})+\cdots.$$
Add the two, simplify.

Comment: If we were given to calculate E(x^2) then how would we proceed as it is an even function

Comment: On the greatest integer, the discrete distribution is symmetric about $-\frac12$

Comment: how would we calculate E(X^2)

Comment: There is symmetry, so it is $2\int_0^\infty x^2e^{-2x}\,dx$. Integration by parts. Or bring the $2$ inside, get $\int_0^\infty (x^2)2e^{-2x}\, dx$. Recognize this as familiar from the exponential function, easy if you know the moment generating function, or if you remember the variance.

Comment: when we solve this integral we get 1/4 .am i right??

Comment: sorry we get 1/2 ...

Comment: I get $\frac{2}{4}$, the second moment of the exponential is $2/\lambda^2$.

Answer (score 1):

1. $f(x)=f(-x)$, so if $E[X]$ exists then $E[X]=0$ as a symmetric random variable.  It does exist, because $E[|X|]$ exists.
2. If $Y=|X|$ then the density of $Y$ is $g(y)=2e^{-2y}$ for positive $y$ and $E[|X|]=E[Y]=\frac12$ as an exponential random variable
3. If $Z=\lfloor X \rfloor $ then $\Pr(Z=n) = \Pr(Z=-(n+1)) = e^{-2n}(1-e^{-2})$ for non-negative integer $n$, so is should be easy to see $E[\lfloor X \rfloor]=E[Z]=-\frac12$.

Comment: I dont understand part 2 when Y=|X| how the density turns out to be 2e^-2y

Comment: shoudnt it be e^-2y as i got my F_y(x)=-e^-(2y)/2 .so when i differentiate it i get e^-2y ad my g(y)

Comment: @user91689:  Take your pick of explanations: (a) Since $X$ is symmetric about $0$, the probability density of $Y$ must be twice the density of $X$ at positive values. (b)  $\Pr(Y \le y) = 1 - e^{-2y}$ with a derivative of $2e^{-2y}$.  (c) In general, the probability density of an [exponential random variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) is of the form $\lambda e{-\lambda x}$.

Comment: thankyou i understood it now and if we were given E[X^2] how would we calculate it since it is an even function now

Comment: $E[X^2]=E[Y^2] = \frac{1}{2}$. In general the $n$th moment of an exponential random variable with rate $\lambda$ is $n!\, \lambda^{-n}$.

Answer (score -3):

**Hint:**

> $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x,  $$

and more generally

> $$\operatorname{E}[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x. $$

To deal with integrals contain the floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/how-to-solve-an-definite-integral-of-floor-valute-function).

Comment: @Downvoter: I do not know what the down vote for? It is the first answer to be posted yet it is a good hint for the OP to start working on his problem.