# Finding the definite integral of $f(x)=[[x]]$.

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

Here $[[x]]$ shall denote the greatest integer function. Evaluate the definite integral $\int_{-2}^{2}2[[x]]dx$

I'm super confused on this problem, can anybody please help me solve this problem.

*P.s.: the $x$ is surrounded by double brackets which I have no idea what they mean.*

Comment: HINT: Draw the graph and think of the integral as the area under the curve.

Comment: I assume you mean you don't know the definition of the greatest integer function.  Your text should contain it, but here it is.  $[[x]]$ is the (unique) integer $n$ such that $n\leq x< n+1$.  It is also known as the floor function.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/how-to-solve-an-definite-integral-of-floor-valute-function).