# How find this integral $\int_{0}^{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\{t\}\right)dt$

Tags: integration

Find the value

> $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-\{t\}\right)dt$$
>   where$\{x\}=x-[x]$

my try: since
$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-t+[t]\right)dt$$
when

> $$k-1\le t<=k,[t]=k-1,k\in Z$$
>   because $x$ is not integer,and maybe $x\to \infty$ so  follow I can't.Thank you

Comment: Check this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/how-to-solve-an-definite-integral-of-floor-valute-function) which involved the floor function.

Comment: A simpler way is to turn it into two integrals (one of 0.5-t and the other of [t]) then just draw [t], it is a very nice step function, the easiest thing to integrate!

Comment: *second easiest, the constant function would be the easiest, a step function is a sum of these :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $[x]=p$ then write
$$\int_0^x f(t)dt=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\int_k^{k+1}f(t)dt+\int_p^x f(t)dt$$

**Added**

$$\int_0^x[t]dt=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\int_k^{k+1}[t]dt+\int_p^x [t]dt=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\int_k^{k+1}k\ dt+\int_p^x p\ dt\\=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}k+p(x-p)=\frac{p(p-1)}{2}+p(x-p)$$

There's no problem to calculate the integral 
$$\int_0^x\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right) dt$$
and you have $F(x)$.

Comment: I have use this  Euler-Maclaurin summion,But I can't find this $F(x)$ form,can you post full your solution?Thank you

Comment: @nanchangjian I edited my answer.

Comment: Nice.Thank you very much @SamiBenRomdhane

Comment: You're welcome @chinamath

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I made this question favorited just case of your approach. :+)

Comment: Nicely done, Sami! +1