# Floor function as an inverse Mellin transform of Riemann zeta function

Tags: residue-calculus, riemann-zeta, ceiling-and-floor-functions, mellin-transform

We have $$\lfloor x \rfloor=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\zeta(s)\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds\;\;\;(c>1)$$
If I apply residue theorem I get:
$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{x^s \zeta (s)}{s},0\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\text{Res}\left(\frac{x^s \zeta (s)}{s},1\right)=x$$
So I get:
$$\lfloor x \rfloor=x-\frac{1}{2}$$
Which is obviously not correct.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: @tired How to incorporate it?

Comment: sorry there is no branch cut

Comment: do you know this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751948/mellin-transform-of-the-floor-function

Comment: @tired It does not seem they tried to apply residue theorem there...

Comment: The residue theorem doesn't apply because $$\lim_{\sigma \to -
 \infty} \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\frac{\zeta(s)}{s} x^s\ne 0$$ @tired

Comment: For $c > 1$ and $x > 0, x \not \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lfloor x \rfloor=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\zeta(s)\frac{x^{s}}{s}ds$ is true by inverse Mellin/Laplace/Fourier transform.

Comment: @reuns I would accept your comments also as a correct answer. Is there any chance that if choosing different function inside inverse transform that zeros of zeta would also "predict" (count) integer numbers? i.e. that zeros of zeta would be incorporated in definition of floor function.

Comment: No. The zeros of $\zeta(s)$ define $\log \zeta(s)$ which is the Laplace transform of the distribution $L(u) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\ln 2} \delta(u-\ln n)$ and the Euler product says that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \underbrace{L \ast \ldots \ast L}_k(u) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \delta(u-\ln n)$ where $\ast$ is the convolution.

Comment: That's is to say you won't get anything better than the Hadamard factorization of $\zeta(s)$ (in term of its zeros)