# An integral involving two variables and the floor function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $N$ be some fixed positive integer. I have the following function
$$
g(z) = z \int_1^N [t] e^{2 \pi i t z} \ dt.
$$
How would one compute
$$
\int_0^1 g(z) \ dz ?
$$
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct: break $g(z)$ into parts, so  $$g(z) = z \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \int_{t=k}^{k+1} k e^{2 \pi i t z} \, dt = z \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} k \biggl[ \frac{e^{2 \pi i t z}}{2 \pi i z} \biggr]_{t=k}^{k+1}.$$  Then see if you can simplify this sum, and then integrate it with respect to $z$.

Answer (score 0):

First change the order of integration and evaluate the inner integral which is with respect to $z$ using integration by parts, then advance to evaluate the integral involving the floor function. See [related techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/how-to-solve-an-definite-integral-of-floor-valute-function).

Comment: Thank you very much for this also!

Comment: @TomMosher: You are very welcome.