# How to find $\int_0^1 \frac {\mathrm dx}{\left \lfloor{1-\log_2(1-x)}\right \rfloor}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We want to evaluate;

$$\int_0^1 \frac {\mathrm dx}{\left \lfloor{1-\log_2(1-x)}\right \rfloor}$$

The $\left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor$ is the floor function. I have made no progress so far.

Comment: Is the floor on the entire denominator?

Comment: Yes. Fixing latex, just wait.

Comment: I'll fix it for you 1 sec.

Comment: Definitely not the right stackexchange, but why do you use $$ instead of $ and how do you make it bigger and centered?

Comment: The two dollar signs make it centered and bigger, but it's a block DOM object whereas one dollar sign is an inline-block and thus smaller.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by graphing. If you mean a numerical solution, no I'm looking for an analytical one.

Comment: No I meant that to solve where the denominator change, but I can do it without it (I think)

Comment: Actually never mind, I have no idea :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16601/discussion-between-user148432-and-shahar).

Comment: @user148432: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866304/proving-int-01-frac-mathrmdx1-lfloor-log-21-x-rfloor-2-log-2/866618#866618).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integrand function is constant on a sequence of intervals, in particular:
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\left\lfloor 1-\log_2 x\right\rfloor}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2^{1-n}-2^{-n}}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-n}}{n}=\color{red}{\log 2.}$$

Comment: I can see by the graph why it would be a sum and I was trying to find similarities and paterns, how did you end up with that particular sum so fast?

Comment: By just looking on which intervals the integrand function equals $\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\ldots$.

Comment: Didn't you consider $n = 0$ ?. Because $\large\int_{0}^{1}{{\rm d}x \over \left\lfloor\,1 - \log_{2}\left(x\right)\,\right\rfloor} = \ln\left(2\right)\int_{0}^{\infty}{2^{1 - x} \over \left\lfloor\,x\,\right\rfloor}\,\dd x$