# integral involving greatest integer function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ and $I_n=\int_1^n \frac{x-[x]}{x^2}dx$. Then, what is $S_{10} + T_{10}$?

The only clue that i can get is break the limits of integration according as the value the greatest integer function takes???please solve this for me. The answer i got was $\ln10 + 1$.

Comment: This is a [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360323/how-to-solve-an-definite-integral-of-floor-valute-function).

Comment: please just solve my problem am confused

Comment: Why should we solve your problem? We're happy to try to help you learn, but that is (absolutely) not the same as just doing math for you.

Comment: In fact, "just solve my problem" is a particular kind of "off-topic".

Answer (score 3):

**Hint 1:**

> \begin{align}\int_1^n \frac{x-[x]}{x^2}dx &= \int_1^2 \frac{x-1}{x^2} dx+\int_2^3\frac{x-2}{x^2} dx + \cdots + \int_{n-1}^n\frac{x-n+1}{x^2} dx\end{align}

**Hint 2:**

> \begin{align}\int_{n-1}^n \frac{n-1}{x^2}dx&=\left[\frac{(1-n)}{x}\right]_{n-1}^n\\&=(1-n)\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{n}\end{align}

Can you proceed from it?

Comment: yes i have done it like this..but still if you could show the working and steps

Comment: I added one more hint. But you have to proof the problem yourself eventually.