# If $ I = \int_0^\pi \sin(\sin^{-1}\{x\})dx $ then what is $\big[I\big]$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, solution-verification

I was working on the following question:

If $$ I =  \int_0^\pi \sin(\sin^{-1}\{x\})dx $$
then what is $\big[I\big]$? ($ \{x\} $ means the fractional part of $x$)

My solution went like this: $\sin(\arcsin\{x\}) = \{x\}.$ So the integral simply reduces to:

$$ I =  \int_0^\pi \{x\}dx $$
$$ I =  3\int_0^1 x dx + \int_0^{ \pi-3 }xdx $$

So, $\big[I\big] = 1$.

But the *given* solution went like this:

$$ 0 \le \{x\} < 1 $$
$$ 0 \le \arcsin{\{x\}}<\pi/2$$
$$ 0 \le \sin(\arcsin{\{x\})} < 1$$
$$ \int_0^\pi0dx \le \int_0^\pi\sin(\arcsin{\{x\})} < \int_0^\pi1dx$$
$$ \int_0^\pi0dx \le I < \int_0^\pi1$$

So $\big[ I \big] = 3$.

Now, who is wrong? I believe that the given solution is wrong because the inequality used is strict, so even if $3 <\pi$, still $1<\pi$ holds true. But still,
$$ 0 \le \sin(\arcsin{\{x\})} < 1$$

which follows from
$$ 0 \le \{x\} < 1 $$

is like $\sin(\arcsin{\{x\})}$ takes *all* values lesser than one, even those like $0.9999...$ So, the solution still makes 'sense', if thought qualitatively.

Comment: I like your work better; in fact, I don't understand the given solution. But I could be wrong.

Comment: What is it with the given solution that you don't understand? (The only fault I can find is what I already pointed out)

Comment: Have a look at this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266110/simple-integral-help/266134#266134) which has some related techniques.

Comment: I don't understand why $0 \leq I < \pi$ means that $\lfloor I \rfloor = 3$.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to tell! So, maybe the given solution is erroneous?

Comment: @EricAuld That's because it doesn't. That only says it could be one of $0,\,1,\,2,\,3$.

Comment: The right answer is  $$ I =  3\int_0^1 x dx + \int_0^{ \pi-3 }xdx=\frac 3 2 +\frac {(\pi-3)^2} 2 =\frac 1 2 \,{\pi }^{2}-3\,\pi +6=1.51002.$$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, in the problem you told me to see, I don't understand the line $$ = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{1}{y^3} (1+n)(y-n)\, dy= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2} $$. I could've asked there, but asking here would give an instant reply, so.

Comment: @user64494 The $[I]$ is the greatest integer part, aka Gauss bracket or floor.

Comment: @ParthThakkar: Just evaluate the integral and you will see it.

Comment: The inequalities $0 \le I,\, I< \pi$ do not imply $[I]=3. $–

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to the given solution, yours is correct and clear. Maybe a bit brief, adding a "thus $\frac{3}{2} \leqslant I < 2$ between

$$I = 3\int_0^1 x\,dx + \int_0^{\pi-3} x\,dx$$

and "So, $[I] = 1$" would not be detrimental. Depending on what you may consider obvious, adding further intermediate steps could be demanded or superfluous.

In the given solution, from

$$\int_0^\pi 0\,dx \leqslant I < \int_0^\pi 1\, dx$$

one can only deduce $0 \leqslant [I] \leqslant 3$, which of the four possible values is the correct one must be determined by other means. The reported answer $[I] = 3$ is, as shown by your calculation, simply wrong.