# Can the following integral be computed?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can the following integral be computed?

[image]

Comment: "**Can** the following integral **be** computed?"

Comment: Sorry........ :-)

Comment: You can, but it is slightly messy. Divide $[0,1]$ into intervals where $\{1/x\}$ is continuous and has an easy expression.

Comment: A  [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266110/simple-integral-help/266134#266134).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: consider $$A_n=\int_{1/(n+1)}^{1/n}\{1/x\}^{4}dx$$. This can be computed. Does the series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ converges?

Comment: Sketch $\{\frac{1}{x}\}^4$ between 0 and 1.  You will find that it is bounded above by a simple function.  So the integral you want is bounded above by a simple integral.

Comment: please someone tell me the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With some preliminary transformations (in attachement) the integral is reduced to the integral of a polygamma function which is known (I let WolframAlpha do the known part of the job).
[image]

Comment: Numerical computations with *Maple* and *Mathematica* confirm the result.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's prove that it converges:

$$\int_0^1\bigg\{\frac1x\bigg\}^4dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{\{t\}^4}{t^2}dt\color{red}<\int_1^\infty\frac{1^4}{t^2}dt=\bigg[-\frac1t\bigg]_1^\infty=1,\qquad\text{since }0\le\{t\}<1.$$

---

$$\int_0^1\bigg\{\frac1x\bigg\}^4dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{\{t\}^4}{t^2}dt=\sum_1^\infty\int_k^{k+1}\frac{(t-k)^4}{t^2}dt=\sum_1^\infty\int_0^1\frac{u^4}{(u+k)^2}du=$$

$$=\sum_1^\infty\bigg(\frac43-2k+4k^2-\frac1{k+1}+4k^3\ln\frac k{k+1}\bigg)=\ldots<1$$