# An integral representation for $\psi$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, euler-mascheroni-constant

Let  $\displaystyle \gamma$ denote the Euler constant defined by $\displaystyle \gamma := \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac11+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n- \log n\right)$.

Here is an integral for $\gamma$.

> $$
> \gamma = \int_0^1 \frac{ \left\{1/x\right\}1/x}{\lfloor1/x\rfloor}  \mathrm{d}x 
> $$

where $\displaystyle \left\{x\right\}$ and $\displaystyle \lfloor x \rfloor$ denote the **fractional part** and the **integer part** of $x$ respectively.

We may generalize the previous result.

Let $z$ be a complex number such that $\Re{z}>-1$. Then

> $$  
> \psi(z+1) =\int_{0}^{1} \frac{z-\left\{1/x\right\}}{z+\lfloor1/x\rfloor} \: \frac{\mathrm{d}x }{x}
> $$ 
>   where $\displaystyle \psi:= \Gamma'/\Gamma.$

Could you prove it?

Comment: Why do you say it is new?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews As far as I know, it is new :)!

Comment: Why do you think it is true?

Comment: @Hoseyn Heydari This is a (small) challenging question. Thanks.

Comment: Just usually we try to avoid bragging in questions, and just because you haven't seen a trivial result...

Comment: Sorry, I see. But I can give a general result, maybe this one is not standard.

Comment: Useful [techniques](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266110/simple-integral-help/266134#266134).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute $x=\frac{1}{u}$. Then $\frac{1}{x}dx = \frac{1}{x}\frac{-1}{u^2}du  = -\frac{1}{u}du$.

So $$\int_{1}^\infty \frac{\{u\}}{u\lfloor u\rfloor}du = \int_{1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{\lfloor u\rfloor}-\frac{1}{u}\right) du = \gamma$$

Comment: Ok, it is not new at all! :)

Comment: I think it is fair to accept this answer which was appropriate to the initial question! Tell me... Thanks!