# computing an integration with a floor function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am trying to compute 
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{x} -  \biggl\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\biggr\rfloor\right) dx$$ 
with no success.
Any hints?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266110/simple-integral-help/266134#266134).

Comment: It is more or less the definition of the Euler-Mascheroni constant: $$\gamma = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(H_n-\log n\right).$$

Comment: Let $t=\dfrac1x$ and then decompose the resulting integral into a series of integrals.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{x} - \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right) dx=\lim_{k\to +\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{k}}^1 \left(\frac{1}{x} - \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right) dx$$

Now to compute the other integral use the decomposition:
$$\int_{\frac{1}{k}}^1 \left(\frac{1}{x} - \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right) dx=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \int_{\frac{1}{i+1}}^{\frac{1}{i}}\left(\frac{1}{x} -i\right)dx=\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\left[\ln(x)-ix\right]_{\frac{1}{i+1}}^{\frac{1}{i}}$$

and you can compute this sum and determine the limit, After computation you obtain:

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}\left[\ln(x)-ix\right]_{\frac{1}{i+1}}^{\frac{1}{i}}=\ln(k)-\sum_{i=2}^{k}\frac{1}{i}$$

and this gives you:

> $$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{x} - \left\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor\right) dx=1-\gamma$$

with $\gamma$ denotes [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

Answer (score 0):

Split it into a sum of integrals over intervals for which you know the value of the floor term. Note that this will be an infinite sum.